# speed up long running query on huge tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am facing with problematic query on Azure SQL database, which I need to speed up.

This is my query:

```
SELECT  
    [Incidents].[Incident_Number], 
    [Incidents].[Incidentinteraction], 
    [Incidents].[Incidentid], 
    [Address].[Ads_Sk]
FROM
    [schema1].[Address] AS Address            --3529046 rows
JOIN 
    [schema2].[Incidents] AS Incidents  --3268375 rows
    ON Incidents.[Ads_Sk_Incidentaddress] = Address.[Ads_Sk]
```

Address table has 2 indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE [schema1].[ADDRESS] 
ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ADS_SK] ASC, [ISCURRENTRECORD] ASC, [RECORDSTARTDATE] ASC) 
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and a non-clustered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_ADDRESS_ADS_CURRENT] 
ON [PROMISE_CDW].[ADDRESS] ([ADS_SK] ASC, [ISCURRENTRECORD] ASC) 
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Incident table has also two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE [schema2].[INCIDENTS] 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([INCIDENTID] ASC, [ISCURRENTRECORD] ASC, [RECORDSTARTDATE] ASC) 
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_ADDRESS_ADS_SK_INCIDENT_NUMBER] 
ON [schema2].[INCIDENTS] ([ADS_SK_INCIDENTADDRESS] ASC, [INCIDENT_NUMBER] ASC) 
   INCLUDE ([INCIDENTID], [INCIDENTINTERACTION]) 
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

I got my results after 22 seconds and this is unacceptable for business users.

How can I speed up this query?

Thank you in advance for any hint

Comment: Can you post the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share the link?  Also, check out these blog sites, there is a lot of great information on query tuning:  https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/blog/ or https://www.brentozar.com/blog/

Comment: Here is my execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk4FvnElv

also - I know Brent and Eric blogs. I just got stuck with this query and just simply dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query doesn't need a join, all the fields you're selecting belong to the `Incidents` table.

You're only using the `Address` table to filter rows that don't have `Incidents.[Ads_Sk_Incidentaddress]` as part of `Address.[Ads_Sk]`, which is something you can easily do in a `where` clause with an `in`.

Comment: I'm ashamed of myself. @Blindy - you're totally right. I tried to analyze it for so long and I haven't noticed this obvious mistake here.Thanks!